# Enable a CentOS 7 server send email via SSL

Tags: centos, ssl, email

I have a CentOS 7 server running lampp, with domain name **xxx.example.com**. I have successfully config the SSL certificate for **https://xxx.example.com**.

For email notification purpose, I need to send some emails. My smtp server's domain is **smtp.example.com**. I **could** send email in my local environment (Windows 10, xampp) with SSL activated. But when I deploy the site on CentOS, it can't send email with SSL option activated. I have to bypass the SSL verification part to send the email:

```
 'stream' => [
         'ssl' => [
                'allow_self_signed' => true,
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
          ],
  ],
```

So, how should I set up my CentOS environment to send email with SSL correctly?

Comment: What host name is your application connecting to? How have you verified that, besides your *https* service, you also configured your *smtp* service to use an appropriate host name & certificate?

Comment: My email program connects to `smtp.example.com`. I could successfully send the email with SSL in my local requirement. So I suppose the smtp server should be OK.  I didn't control the smtp server, so I can't config and verify the certificate.